# Link in Wiki Source Box

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, wikipedia

I have an internal wiki I am using powered by MediaWiki. I am trying to add link within a

```
<source lang="c"></source>
```

area. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: I think the `source` tag is not native to MediaWiki. If that is correct, which extension do you use for it? You might be better off asking for help about that particular extension or even contact the developers of that extension (each extension has its own 'talk' page), rather than presenting this as a general MediaWiki question.

Answer (score 2):

This question is probably about the [SyntaxHighlight GeSHi extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSyntaxHighlight_GeSHi), that is bundled with newer versions of MediaWiki (so some users might not think of it as an extension). In that case, the answer is **no**.

The extension generates a `<pre>` element, that can, by definition, not include links.